# R: iterate through list of coordinates (indices) to find entries in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, data.table, apply

I have a matrix called `coordinates` that tells me where to find the entries I want in another matrix called `data`. For example:

```
set.seed(0)
coordinates <- matrix(c(1, 2, 
                        5, 3, 
                        4, 3), 
                       nrow = 2)
rownames(coordinates) <- c("x","y") # optional - I added this clarity
data <- matrix(rbinom(25, 1, 0.5), 5) # makes a 5x5 matrix of 1's and 0's
```

I would like a function to return the sum of the entries located at these coordinates. In this case:

```
data[1,2] + data[5,3] + data[4,3]
```

I assume there's some clever use of map, Map, or the apply family that can accomplish this succinctly? I'm open to using data.table, tidyverse, etc. as well as converting `coordinates` to some other form.

Answer (score 2):

We can extract the elements with row/column index and then use `sum` on the extracted elements

```
sum(data[cbind(c(1, 5, 4), c(2, 3, 3))])
```

---

Or convert the 'coordinates' into two column matrix by `cbind`ing the first and second row

```
sum(data[cbind(coordinates[1,], coordinates[2,])])
```

Or as @markus mentioned in the comments

```
sum(data[t(coordinates)])
```